# Flutter dialog dismiss listener

Tags: flutter

```
Future<int> _show() async {
  return await showDialog<int>(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        actions: [
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 1), // returning 1
            child: Text('1'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 2), // returning 2
            child: Text('2'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I am calling this function as:

```
int value = await _show();
```

The problem comes when the user taps outside of dialog to dismiss it. In that case the above `value` returns `null`. I want to return `0` if that happens. The solutions I have are:

- Set `barrierDismissible: false` which I don't want to do.
- I can check if `value` is null, and infer that the dialog was dismissed by clicking on outside region.

But besides these, is there any better approach or any dialog dismissible listener from where I can return `Navigator.pop(0)` in case dialog is dismissed by tapping outside region, something like this:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  onDialogDismissed: () {
    Navigator.pop(0);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you want exists. I think the closest you can get to that expectation of elegancy could be this:

```
Future<int> _show() async {
  return await showDialog<int>(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        actions: [
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 1), // returning 1
            child: Text('1'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 2), // returning 2
            child: Text('2'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ) ?? 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `showDialog` returns a `Future` and therefore has a `then` method. The `then` callback is called whenever the dialog is dismissed.
example:

```
showDialog(
  //Dialog Code
).then((val){
  //code after dialog is dismissed
});

//or:
showGeneralDialog(
  //Dialog Code
).then((val){
  //code after dialog is dismissed
});
```